# chef deploy start service and restart service in sequence

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I was reading https://serverfault.com/questions/378520/chef-stop-and-start-service-in-sequence and would like to ask different procedure.

Step 1: framework bootstrap to jboss service

```
bash "bootstrap application" do
    code <<-EOF
    ant bootstrap
    EOF
end
```

Step 2: then start jboss

```
service "jboss" do
    action :start
end
```

Step 3: install application

```
bash "install application" do
    code <<-EOF
    ant install
    EOF
end
```

in between step 2 and 3, ant install returns error because jboss is not started yet. But successful on the 2nd run. Obviously step 3 doesnt know if the jboss already started.

How to do this on chef?

Comment: Could you paste the output somewhere? The service should be running after Step 2

Comment: Maybe JBoss hasn't had the time to come up when step 3 is executed. In this case, the service will be technically up, but JBoss wouldn't be listening for requests yet. You'd have to come up with a way to monitor JBoss's service port or its log to make sure that step 3 only runs after JBoss is actually up.

Comment: If it is a timing issue, then a simple solution is add a "waitfor" statement to your "install" target: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html

Comment: I gave an answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/546901/chef-deploy-start-service-and-restart-service-in-sequence/547230#547230). one key problem here is, you can't know if jboss is started successfully even the service jboss is started. it takes time. So you'd better improve your ant target to retry or use `retries` attribute in `bash[install application]` resource

Comment: @MarkO'Connor the build.xml is generated dynamically from external package, i cant do that. though its more straightforward.

Comment: @shawnzhu yes.. checking it out.

Comment: @cbl exactly. thats what im asking. currently doing and testing for ruby_block by chef. ill keep this posted.

Comment: @StephenKing 1st output would be Connection Refused when ant installing to jboss. but after a while (probably jboss already started in the background) and try ant install again, it goes through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i have done this from ruby_block

```
# for managing service
# jboss block until operational
ruby_block "block_until_operational" do
  block do
    until IO.popen("netstat -lnt").entries.select { |entry|
        entry.split[3] =~ /:#{node[:jboss][:default_port]}$/
      }.size == 1   
      Chef::Log.debug "service[jboss] not listening on port #{node[:jboss][:default_port]}"
      sleep 1
    end
  end
  action :nothing
end
```

i created this ruby block that would listen to port 8080 until it returns 1 (started)
and called this via

```
service "jboss" do
    action :start
    notifies :create, 'ruby_block[block_until_operational]', :immediate
end
```